# Web Services using Ajax in phonegap

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, web-services, cordova

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function session()
{
        storage = window.localStorage;
        key= $('#T_id').val();
        value= $('#T_Password').val();
            storage.setItem(key,value);
    }
function validate()
{
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["T_id"].value;
    var y = document.forms["myForm"]["T_Password"].value;
var filter =/^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$/;
if (!filter.test(x)) {
    alert('Please provide a valid email address');    
    return false;
        }
 if(true){
var email=$('#T_id').val();
var password=$('#T_Password').val(); 
// var data = $(this).serializeArray(); // convert form to array
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
url: "192.168.3.1:8080/SmartAttendanceSystem46/loginUserRestService/getUserModel",
data: {"Email": escape(email), "password": escape(password)},
dataType : 'json',
contentType: "application/json", 

                 success : function(data) {
                    alert("Uploaded! "+data);
                     session();
                   window.location.href="PHOTOFROMGALLERY.html";
                 },
                 error : function(request, error) {
                alert("Error! " + error+" "+request);

                 }
  }); 
 }
return( true );
    }
    </script>
        <form action="" method="post" name="myForm">
<input type="email" name="T_id" id="T_id"/>
<input type="password" id="T_Password" name="T_Password"/>
<input type="button" value="Login" id="loginButton" onclick="validate();">
</html>
```

Why the ajax calls error method ? i wanna send email and password to "url" if the user is authentic the java webservices returns success.. web service of java is okay, but why the data is not reached at this url ... please help

Answer (score 0):

try testing it on real device or on WAMP server . sometimes test enviroment can't get get data from server . (i do not know why myself!) .
hoped it helps ;)

Comment: this is a phonegap application.....i am running it using cellphone connected with wifi.. i dont understand what you say

Comment: i know that , just build your apk file and run it on device. it solved my problem.

Comment: Is your wampp server in same network?it only works if both are in same network(ie  phone and wamp server)